# Binding a Listbox's SelectedItem to a property in an Instance of a static class

Tags: wpf, binding, static-classes

I have a simple listbox in a template file as follows:

```
<local:ProcessVisualization x:Key="ProcessVisualization"/>

<ListBox Grid.Column="1" 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=ProcessVisualization}, Path=Instance.TestListItems}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=ProcessVisualization}, Path=Instance.SelectedTestListItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
</ListBox>
```

Then in my ProcessVisualization class I have the following:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _testListItems;
private string _selectedTestListItem;
private static readonly ProcessVisualization _processVisualization = new ProcessVisualization();

public ObservableCollection<string> TestListItems
{
    get { return _testListItems; }
    set
    {
        _testListItems = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("TestListItems");
    }
}

public string SelectedTestListItem
{
    get { return _selectedTestListItem; }
    set
    {
        _selectedTestListItem = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedTestListItem");
    }
}

public static ProcessVisualization Instance
    {
        get { return _processVisualization; }
    }
```

When I run methods that assign lists of strings to TestListItems, they show up properly in my listbox, and I can set SelectedTestListItem from code without issue. But if a user tries to pick from the listbox, it doesn't seem to get back to updating my property on the ProcessVisualization class. Anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: What is that static `Instance` good for? The `ProcessVisualization` resource is already an instance of that class. And you already use it as binding source.

Comment: well hot damn, I took out Instance and it worked. I was told originally that you needed a static member to bind to. Must have been I didn't understand the original source code correctly.

Comment: The guy that worked on this code originally is out of the office, but when he get's back, I'll ask him and post the insight I gather.

Comment: At least in the example code here the static property doesn't make any sense. You can always access the resource object, also from code-behind if necessary.